# Data Conversion Error H2 Database

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-update, h2

I am running a database query from Java Application.

```
String id = app.getVariable("Product Id"),
                name = app.getVariable("Product Name"),
                rate = app.getVariable("Rate"),
                type = app.getVariable("Type"),
                desc = app.getVariable("Description"),
                qty = app.getVariable("Quantity"); // Returns String from TextFields

        type = type.equalsIgnoreCase("LIMITED") ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";


        try {
            String query = "UPDATE COUNTER.PRODUCTS SET TITLE = ? AND RATE = ? AND IS_LIMITED = ? AND DESCRIPTION = ? WHERE ID = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = MainApp.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);

            stmt.setString(1, name);
            stmt.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble(rate));
            stmt.setBoolean(3, Boolean.parseBoolean(type));
            stmt.setString(4, desc);
            stmt.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(id));

            stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch(Exception ex1){
            System.out.println( ex1.toString() );
        }
```

But SQLException is encountered

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "Scanning"; SQL statement:
>   UPDATE COUNTER.PRODUCTS SET TITLE = ? AND RATE = ? AND IS_LIMITED = ? AND DESCRIPTION = ? WHERE ID = ? [22018-187]

Insert data query works fine but I am unable to execute the update query.

Comment: http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your query like this:

```
  UPDATE COUNTER.PRODUCTS SET TITLE = ? ,RATE = ? ,IS_LIMITED = ? ,DESCRIPTION = ? WHERE ID = ?
```

With using comma `,` instead of `and`.